# Windows 10 connecting to external SMB share

Tags: windows, network-share, network-attached-storage, file-sharing, server-message-block

I currently have a Synology NAS at my office that I wish to connect to remotely with SMB. This works perfectly fine on my MacBook, I use finder to connect with `smb:\\<domainname>\<share>`, but I cannot do the same on the Windows 10 machine. The network environment is exactly the same. I tried mapping a networking drive with `\\<IP>\<share>` and `\\<domainname>\<share>` but it fails to connect every time. 
Any suggestions on how to get it to work?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Fails to connect? Do you get any messages/errors? Also, make sure you're using backslashes in the entire UNC path. You've still got forward slashes in your question and I'm unsure if that's a typo or if that's actually how you're trying to connect.

Comment: It says "The folder does not appear to be valid. Please choose another." I have corrected my typos above.

Comment: Can you navigate to just the hostname? (i.e. do not go to the shared folder, just the IP address/hostname.)

Answer (score 3):

You must use backslashes and not forwardslashes:

```
 \\<domainname>\share
```

Comment: Oh sorry, that was a typo in my original original question, I’ll fix it now!

Answer (score 1):

Not enough details provided, so many reasons can be behind this problem which looks to be related to the Windows machine. Try to verify these steps :

1. Check if NetBIOS is active on the machine : [Activate NetBIOS](http://ecross.mvps.org/howto/enable-netbios-over-tcp-ip-with-windows.htm)
2. Check smb version : [SMB version Check](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-access-files-network-devices-using-smbv1-windows-10)
3. Check your firewall and settings related.
4. Check the rights in the NAS server : the user you are connecting with in Windows has the rights to access that folder.

Note that smb/CIFS has many issues with Windows.

Comment: NetBIOS is not required to access a share. It is also a security problem and should not be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  Except it was working until I updated the firmware and then it stopped working on Windows.  It turns out that new firmware unticked NYLMv1 authentication.  And it seems that by default Windows uses this.

You can reconfigure Windows to use NTLMv2.  Or you can enable NTLMv1 in the Synology setup.  **If you take the latter approach, you should read the warning**
[Security guidance for NTLMv1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/security-guidance-for-ntlmv1-and-lm-network-authentication-da2168b6-4a31-0088-fb03-f081acde6e73)

To tick it.

1. Open **Control Panel** App
2. Select **File Services** on the Left Hand Menu
3. Select **Others** Tab
4. Tick **Enable NTLMv1 authentication**